# Duvida com Select usando ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, inner-join

Estou tentando fazer um `SELECT` de modo que exiba da segunda tabela somente o registro mais recente.

Tentei fazer isso usando `GROUP BY` e `ORDER BY`, porém com o `GROUP BY` meu `SELECT` não funciona, somente com o `ORDER BY`, tentei usar `SELECT TOP 1` porém o resultado não saiu como esperado, exibindo somente o registro mais recente de todos.

```
Tabela A = ID_A , Produto, Tipo | Tabela B = ID_A, ID_B, Descricao, dt_renovacao
```

As tabelas estão associadas e eu estou tentando selecionar o id, produto e tipo da **Tabela A** e juntamente, o id, descricao e dt_renovacao, da **Tabela B**, usando como critério, o registro com a dt_renovacao mais recente da tabela B.

Ou seja, para cada registro da Tabela A será exibido somente um único registro da tabela B que deve ser o mais recente.

O código que eu fiz é esse:

```
SELECT A.id_a, A.produto, A.tipo, B.id_B, B.descricao, B.dt_renovacao 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id_a = B.id_a GROUP BY B.id_a ORDER BY B.dt_renovacao DESC
```

Comment: id_a e id_B são chaves primárias?

Comment: Ambas são primarias e auto increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tente com subselect e max

```
select  
    A.id_a, A.produto, A.tipo,  
    B.id_B, B.descricao, B.dt_renovacao
from tabela_A A,tabela_B B
where B.id_B =  A.id_a
and B.dt_renovacao = (select max(B1.dt_renovacao)
                      from tabela_B B1
                      where B1.id_B = B.id_B)
```

Comment: Fiz dessa, maneira e deu certo, porém o max eu substitui por TOP 1 e usei order by no final, agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

A solução que eu encontrei foi incluir um campo de data de atualização na primeira tabela, e depois com select, o inner join eu coloquei pras duas datas serem igual assim como o código e funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode como nosso colega Motta mencionou acima, usando SubSelect com MAX.

Ou:

```
SELECT A.id_a, A.produto, A.tipo, B.id_B, B.descricao, B.dt_renovacao 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id_a = B.id_a GROUP BY B.id_a ORDER BY B.dt_renovacao DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY
```

Onde o 5 seria o número de valores que você quer retornar.

Answer (score 0):

```
--Resultado desejado
select  tmp.*, b.descricao 
from    (
        select    distinct(a.id_a)
                , a.produto
                , a.tipo
                , max(b.dta_renovacao) as dta_renovacao
        from    tab_a a
                left join tab_b b on
                    b.id_a = a.id_a 
        group by a.id_a, a.produto, a.tipo
        ) as tmp
        inner join tab_b as b on
            b.dta_renovacao = tmp.dta_renovacao
;

--Query mais elegante mas sem uma das colunas
select    distinct(a.id_a)
                , a.produto
                , a.tipo
                , max(b.dta_renovacao) as dta_renovacao
        from    tab_a a
                left join tab_b b on
                    b.id_a = a.id_a 
        group by a.id_a, a.produto, a.tipo
```

Ver online http://tpcg.io/iLzByAzk

```
CREATE TABLE tab_a (
    id_a serial NOT NULL,
    produto varchar NULL,
    tipo varchar NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tab_b (
    id_b serial NOT NULL,
    id_a int4 NOT NULL,
    descricao varchar NULL,
    dta_renovacao timestamp NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO tab_a (id_a,produto,tipo) VALUES 
(1,'Produto 1','Tipo 1')
,(2,'Produto 2','Tipo 2')
,(3,'Produto 3','Tipo 3')
,(4,'Produto 4','Tipo 4')
;

INSERT INTO tab_b(id_b,descricao,dta_renovacao,id_a) VALUES 
(1,'descricao 1 1','2020-04-15 00:00:01.000',1)
,(2,'descricao 1 2','2020-04-15 00:00:02.000',1)
,(3,'descricao 1 3','2020-04-15 00:00:03.000',1)
,(4,'descricao 2 1','2020-04-15 00:00:04.000',2)
,(5,'descricao 2 2','2020-04-15 00:00:05.000',3)
;
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa tarde, eu tentaria fazer assim:

```sql
select  
    A.id_a, A.produto, A.tipo,  
    B.id_B, B.descricao, B.dt_renovacao

from tabela_A A 

left join tabela_B B On B.id_B =  A.id_a

ORDER BY B.dt_renovacao DESC
```

Comment: Esse código infelizmente não seu, ele me retornou todos os documentos com todas as versão, talvez um group by seja a solução, mas tá aí um problema que não consegui aplicar